# Django filtering for related fields

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following structure:

```
class FlowerSpecies(models.Model):
  pass

class Months(models.Model):
  flower_species = models.ForeignKey(FlowerSpecies)
  month_idx = models.IntegerField()
```

In words, I have a bunch of flower species each of which can grow in certain months only.

How can I now use filter to query for all the species that grow in June for example?

thanks for help!

Comment: silly me, sorry for the stupid question.... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to do that with

```
FlowerSpecies.objects.filter(months__month_idx=6) #single month
FlowerSpecies.objects.filter(months__month_idx__in=(1,2,3)) #multiple months
```

See Django [Making Queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) documentation page for details

Answer (score 1):

```
FlowerSpecies.objects.filter(months__month_idx=6)
```

Read up on the queries [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships), these things are well documented.